# add event to an ical calendar from a website

Tags: php, web, calendar, icalendar

For a assignment i need to make a booking system for a bnb. It needs to sync to a airbnb calendar which can be exported using ical. but i need to make a new event from the website and i don't know how.

I tried several 3th party programs but they don't only seem to add events to the users calendar. I need to add the event to the airBnB calendar.

I used a script from a third party to display the calendar, all i need now is to add an event.

```
<script src='https://www.accommodationcalendar.com/widget/cwidget.php?calendarID=bbc4c5808a6ade2fd62a66acbea1130b26fe4c0fa922fca106a0728d622d0fa3&col=3&row=4&size=2&lang=english&bg=FFFFFF&dfc=000000&border=CCCCCC&hbg=F1F0F0&hfc=000000&abg=DDFFCC&afc=000000&ubg=FFC0BD&ufc=000000&mobileresize=yes'></script>
```